# C# has something similar to TQuery in Delphi?

Tags: c#, delphi, data-binding, dataset, tquery

I have develop a lot in Delphi and I was asked to work on a new application BUT they prefer that I use C#. It will be like a little erp, with a lot of CRUD operations. In Delphi you have a visual object called TQuery: once you visually define the connection to a specific table in the database, the TQuery define automatically all the CRUD statements. Also you can visually connect a table to this TQuery and all the columns and data will be created automatically: if you start the application and edit the data it will commit automatically. You can also connect textEdit, date and other objects to the columns on the TQuery and everithing will be showed and can be update. I would to know if there is something similar also in c#

I have read about dataset but is not visually and you have to write the query manually, and i have not seen any type of binding to object that represent in real time a datatable in database.

Comment: in C# you would be using Entity Framwork. There are some good editors for VS out there: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=michaelsawczyn.EFDesigner2022

Answer (score 0):

Look into [Entity Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/). It has a visual designer, you can work with C# syntax without having to write much or any SQL. You can start with an existing DB and it will generate your C# classes, or vice versa you can start with C# classes and it will generate your DB objects.

Comment: So your answer is "No, it does not have"?

Comment: There is not a strict Yes or No answer here. Delphi and C# are very different technologies so even similar functionality will have differences such that you cannot say one is equivalent to the other. The closest thing to what DavidS describes is Entity Framework, which will not be exactly the same as TQuery but seems to be the closest thing to it in C#.